# Masterpage check session issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, .net-4.0

I'm fixing my friend's codes. And I have a problem with session value in masterpage.
I'm checking session is null or empty in masterpage and if it's null go to login page.
But other pages that created by masterpage never works.

```
if (Session["user"] != null && Session["user"] != "")
{ }
else
{
    Response.Redirect("/Account/Login.aspx?link=" + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery);
}
```

I tried with Session["user"].ToString() but same result.

And the otherpages have a other controls via this session so it always give error if you are not login.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" CodeFile="document.aspx.cs" Inherits="document" %>
```

Comment: Can you specify in which **page** event are those controls created/using the session. And also, in which **masterpage** event are you checking the session

Comment: For instance i'm creating masterpage which name is back.master and in page_load event i wrote my session control event.
Then i create normal aspx page which name is default.aspx and is derived by back.master and i also write some check codes in page_load event. For ex.
label.text = session["user"].tostring();  
But session control in back.master's page_load fire after default.aspx page_load so it gives me error the "session is null".
But if im creating new web project it's ok, no problem with that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on this:

> But session control in back.master's page_load fire after default.aspx page_load so it gives me error the "session is null"

The root problem here is simple... You need to fully understand the [ASP.Net page life-cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Take a quick look:

[image]

Basically your following assumption is wrong:

> Then i create normal aspx page which name is default.aspx and is **derived by back.master**

From MSDN:

> Master pages behave like child controls on a page: the master page Init event occurs before the page Init and Load events, and the master page Load event occurs after the page Init and Load events

Sadly an ASP.Net **does not derive from a Master Page** Why? because a Master Page is treated as a control so what really happens is that the master page is a child control of the `Page`

### Alternatives:

- Since you are checking if the user is authenticates, it would be better if you rely on the ASP.Net authentication and authorization API

### Workarounds (if you insist to use your own authentication mechanism):

- (Best recommendation) Create a custom `HttpModule` and check the `Session` object there. I think the event that best fits your needs is the: `Application_AuthenticateRequest`. This is a full list of events you can choose from: (BTW there's no need to create a new HttpModule, you could subscribe to events using the *Global.asax* file of your web application, use an HttpModule only if you would like to encapsulate the logic to reuse it)

  - Application_BeginRequest.
  - **Application_AuthenticateRequest.**
  - **Application_PostAuthenticateRequest.**
  - Application_DefaultAuthentication.
  - **Application_AuthorizeRequest.**
  - **Application_PostAuthorizeRequest.**
  - Application_ResolveRequestCache.
  - Application_PostResolveRequestCache.
  - Application_MapRequestHandler. Fired only when the server is running IIS 7 in Integrated Mode and at least >Net Framework 3.0
  - Application_PostMapRequestHandler.
  - Application_AcquireRequestState.
  - Application_PostAcquireRequestState.
  - Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute.
  - The page event handler is executed. (refer to the page life cycle)
  - Application_PostRequestHandlerExecute.
  - Application_ReleaseRequestState.
  - Application_PostReleaseRequestState
  - Application_UpdateRequestCache.
  - Application_PostUpdateRequestCache
  - Application_LogRequest. Fired only when server is IIS 7 Integrated Mode and at least .Net Framework 3.0
  - Application_PostLogRequest. Fired only when server is IIS 7 Integrated Mode and at least .Net Framework 3.0
  - Application_EndRequest.

  For more info:

  - [ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview for IIS 5.0 and 6.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx)
  - [ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview for IIS 7.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx)
- Create a generic page inheriting from `Page` and place the check code there in the `PreLoad` or `Load` event, both events would work and finally inherit all your pages from this page
- (Not recommended) If you want to encapsulate the check inside the Master Page, you could use the `Init` event

Comment: mmm I don't agree w/u, from MSDN: _ASP.NET master pages allow you to create a consistent layout for the pages in your application. A single master page defines the look and feel and standard behavior that you want for all of the pages (or a group of pages) in your application_. Developers used to think about Master Pages in the same way you do, but that's not the case, because they are simply controls to define the **layout of your page**... Yes you could _try_ to encapsulate there your custom logic but that's not the perfect place and if you try you would find problems like this.

Comment: The perfect place to encapsulate common behavior for pages would be the `HttpModule`, or inheriting from a _Parent_ page.

Comment: But let's say like this. In default.aspx has no code. Just Masterpage has the session control. If I want to use default.aspx it's ok. It goes to login.aspx and everything is good.
But when I create another page it never go to login page.
And I also create a web user control to control session and put it in masterpage. So everypage has that usercontrol right. It still does not work.

Comment: In that case, try the following: 1. debug in every page just to be sure that the user control code is being fired (the code checking for the `Session["user"]`) 2. If the code is being fired then there's a problem with the session, either the `Session` is not being set properly when you access the new page or it's been deleted (perhaps the session expires). Check the `Session` configuration in the web.config file (post it here) and be sure that the `Session` is being set in the same way it's set when you access the original  _default.aspx_

Comment: If first I logged in, it's firing. But if I'm not login it's not firing because it gives me session error in other pages.

Comment: Thanks my friend. Ok finally fix the solution. Actually I tried it before but it was not working. I solve the issue with page_init event like this. protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if (Session["master"] != null)
 { }
 else
 {
  Response.Redirect("login.aspx?link=" + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery);
 }
}

Answer (score 1):

IIS has standard methods for authentication and authorization.

If you want to restrict access to certain areas of your website if the user isn't logged in, then there are mechanisms in the configuration that allow for that:

In your web.config you can add:

```
<location path="LoginRequiredDir">
  <system.web>
     <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
     </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

This will automatically take users to the login page if they are not logged in.

Answer (score 1):

Fix: It will solve your issue.

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["master"] != null)
    { }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("login.aspx?link=" + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had similar issue faced. I used `true` to the `Response.Redirect` method so that the rest of load should gets terminated. [Ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt(v=vs.110).aspx). I checked the session value in `Page_Init` of the master page as below.

```
public partial class Dashboard : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["RoleId"] == null || Session["RoleId"].ToString() == "")
        {
            Response.Redirect("/account", true);
        }
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
                setUserInfo();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You define the above code `Page_Load` method in following way:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["user"] != null && Session["user"].ToString() != "")
        {
            //do code here
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("/Account/Login.aspx?link=" + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have set the session of given id i.e user?